# AVPlayer seekToTime: Poor performance while looping short videos

Tags: objective-c, video, loops, avfoundation, avplayer

this is my first question, but I've readed StackOverflow for years.
Well the thing is that I must concatenate a set of videos (MP4) in a particular order, and the last one must loop continuously. Okay, let's try `AVFoundation`.

I've defined all the elements such as `AVComposition`, `AVURLAsset` and `AVPlayerItem`. Then I build the `AVPlayer` and the `AVPlayerLayer`. Everything is okay and the videos are played in the correct order but... (and here comes the problem)

I can note a tiny flick when the AVPlayer passes from one video to the next one. I can ignore that one, but when `AVPlayer` reaches `AVPlayerItem`'s end, and the selector is called for `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification`, I use seekToTime to move the reading head to the correct and then play it again. Works fine, but a GREAT flick is repeated when using seekToTime and playing again. I cannot allow that.

Does anybody know how to repeat the last asset on AVPlayerItem continuously and without flicks?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely stupid,

Friends, when making video manipulation apps be sure that the videos don't have annoying black frames. That was the root of all problems. `[AVPlayer seekToTime:]` works perfectly.

Thanks for your time and patience

Comment: Have you ever tried to pause, then seek to some other part of the same video, and then play? I always notice that before actually showing *the new frames* (i.e. the ones after the jump), the screen shows some *old frames* (i.e. from before the jump). Ever experienced anything like that?